# Is there a way to show all files used during execution of an Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, process, azure-pipelines, execution

During or after running an azure pipeline is there a way to show all files used during that execution ?   Typically a pipeline will call several azure pipeline templates which themselves call further templates ... any step can execute terraform or terragrunt or bash, etc commands which themselves refer to yet other files ...  for reference when a linux process is executing its possible to run `lsof` to show various things including all opened files by user   ...   challenge of offloading execution to these compute cloud providers is that this level of detail is harder to get at ... or is it ?

Comment: Are you referring to the fully expanded YAML, a list of specific files, or a list of specific respoitories?

Answer (score 0):

You get the full expanded files in the pipeline logs which you can download and check what actual CLIs like terraform, bash are used in it.